# multi-geo on OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive

I am trying to set MultiGEO on my SharePoint Online Tenant which has been attached to my MSDN Subscription.

I am following below link and as per the detail on this page, I should see "Geo locations" on left navigation on OneDrive Admin Center.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/administering-a-multi-geo-environment#feedback

But when I navigate on only see below list of option on OneDrive Admin Center.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi-Geo requires 5000 seats minimum and a per-user license. If this is just a personal MSDN tenant, you won't be able to use it.

https://products.office.com/en-us/business/multi-geo-capabilities